# History.js on full screen sections

Tags: jquery, browser-history, pushstate, history.js, popstate

---

I've been working on [a project of mine](http://bramvanroy.be/fullScreenSection/) - the full (important) JavaScript can be found [here](http://bramvanroy.be/fullScreenSection/js/sections.js). I wish to include [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) so that a user can navigate by using the browser's previous and next buttons as well. Also I would like that generated URLs are accessible even though they don't *exist*. These URLs are generated by the history API and therefore are not linked to a HTML document.

### What I've already done

By taking a look at the [API Exposed section](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/README.md#exposed-api) of the plugin and by reading through [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/), I've managed to get this working:

- URLs are correct when navigating with the interface's next, previous and base links
- Titles are correct when navigating with the interface's next, previous and base links

The (stripped down) code for this is:

```
    document.title = $(".parentSection.base").data("title");


// Going forward
    var nextClick = $("a.next_link");

    nextClick.click(function(d) {       
        var nUrl = parentSection.next().data("url");
        History.pushState(null, null, nUrl) ;
        document.title = parentSection.next().data("title");

        d.preventDefault();
    });


// Going backwards
    var prevClick = $("a.prev_link");

    prevClick.click(function(e) {       
        var pUrl = parentSection.prev().data("url");
        History.pushState(null, null, pUrl) ;
        document.title = parentSection.prev().data("title");

        e.preventDefault();
    });


// Going to "Base" position
    var baseClick = $("a.base_link");

    baseClick.click(function(f) {           
        var bUrl = $(".parentSection.base").data("url");
        History.pushState(null, null, bUrl);
        document.title = $(".parentSection.base").data("title");

        f.preventDefault();
    });
```

This works as it should.

### What I can't seem to get done

Even though this works quite neatly it is useless without the final functionalities:

- URL's are now generated (e.g. `/lamp`, `/desk` etc.) but when a user goes directly to one of these links (or simply reloads the page) he or she will get the message that the URL does not exist
- Even though the browser's navigation buttons are clickable (and the
  url changes accordingly) it does not change the content at all.

Can anyone give any feedback on this? I've been working on this for so long now that my behind hurts.

---

I have tried to work from the code that was provided by cjhveal, and thusfar got this (just for testing purposes):

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
        var State = History.getState();
        History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
        $(".parentSection[data-url='" + State.title + "']").css({
            "left": "0",
            "top": "0"
        });
    });
```

Strangely enough, I can't get History.js to log to correct title ... When I log a page it returns like: `"lamp", "bramvanroy.be/fullScreenSection/lamp"` (respectively `title` and `url`) whereas I need to get the title that is defined in the `data-title` object of the section. Yet still, I adjusted the code so tha tit should work `data-url` as defined in section is the same as the `title` attribute that is returned, but still nothing happens!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [usage documentation](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/#working-with-historyjs) for History.js. Make sure you are binding to the state change event, like so:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    // Handle new state.
});
```

As an alternative, some javascript applications make use of the part of the url after the hash, sometimes called the anchor:

`www.myapp.com/app/#/anchor/1`

Changing this part does not require any reloads. Modern browsers even preserve history with pushState. This can be done with the following javascript: `window.location.hash = '/anchor/1'`

EDIT:
One way to make sure that the url is valid is to use query parameters. Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/#working-with-historyjs), we see that instead of full urls, they use query parameters (eg. `?state=1`). Try using something similar, like: `?page=lamp`.

Also, in your click handlers, try passing the title and data through just like in the example.

Comment: If the url doesn't exist on the server then using the anchor seems exactly the right solution.

Comment: So basically what this does is logging the current data, title and url? How can it do that when the url is basically not changing? Or should I call this snippet after I've ran mine (which alters the title and url)? And what then, should I do with this information? I suppose that I should link content to the url, but that is actually my main question. I don't know how to position my elements correctly.

Comment: I have tried your solution and added my findings to my main post.

Comment: This [pull request](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/pull/195) should give you the ability to make this work with one configuration option to force hashes. My only other suggestion is not to use urls, but instead query parameters like in the [examples](https://github.com/balupton/history.js#usage).

Answer (score 1):

Your script should have some function to show "current" url, something like:

```
var display_current=function() {
       //you may use History.getState() here, but i not sure what it will return, so i calculate url myself;
       var url=document.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\//,'');
       if (url == '') {url='home';}
       //Some code here to display current section based on URL
};
```

You should run also that function after loading page:

```
$(function() {display_current();});
```

Then you should handle events of browser history buttons
to handle browser's back/forward buttons use:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
       display_current();
});
```

[here the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate)

To prevent 404 error you have to add .htaccess file to the directory with redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.+$  index.html
```

[more info on mod_rewrite is here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, I hardly understand what you mean (your coherence and grammatical errors confuse me). Can you try to rephrase it all?

Comment: Edited, try to understand, that is not english grammar problem, that more problem in your understanding of programming

Comment: It is not a problem in my understanding of programming, Jesus.. You sentences need to be read three times before I understand them. Also, why would you possibly put a function in a var, rather than just naming the function like so `function display_current() {`? And, you didn't answer the question I asked entirely. "Some code here to display current section" : that's basically my question ...

Comment: The library history.js does nothing about the rendering of the elemenent. You have to write some function to render element based on URL as string.

Comment: I adapted it little to be more history.js, you can experiment with console.log to see how to implement History.getState(), 
about 
var functionname=function(){...}; 
it is just good habbit to not place much trash to global context

Comment: Bram Vanroy: This answer and @eicto's other comments are minimal but pretty much correct. Of course, they are easier to understand when you already know the solution.

Comment: @SeanHogan The thing is, he is answering something that I didn't ask. The URL's are working perfectly already, so is the title but what I need help with, is to find a way of linking a section to its url and its position. I.e. when a user goes to `/lamp` that that section is on the screen and that's something eicto does not answer at all. He answers what I already know, even though I assume that his mod_rewrite function can be helpful.

Comment: @BramVanroy it is your code about linking section, your code did not handle back/forward events and also got 404, that was a question, the position you getting it is your own code, so many ways to render particular section, and i not sure which one you need, if you can do some less complex sample we can help you, but we would not make the code for you without any payment.